# One-to-One relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using E.F db first and I have two tables :

User details :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[detailsUtilisateur] 
(
    [idDetailsUtilisateur] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [nomUtilisateur]       VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [prenomUtilisateur]    VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [compagnieNom]         VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [noTelephone]          NCHAR (10)   NULL,
    [adresse]              VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    [ville]                VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [pays]                 VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [etat]                 VARCHAR (30) NULL,
    [codePostal]           NCHAR (6)    NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_idDetailsUtilisateur] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idDetailsUtilisateur] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_idDetailsUtilisateur] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([idDetailsUtilisateur]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Utilisateur] ([idUtilisateur])
);
```

User

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Utilisateur] 
(
    [idUtilisateur] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [email]         VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [mdp]           VARCHAR (90) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_utilisateur] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idUtilisateur] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([email] ASC)
);
```

I'm trying to add a user, then his details. But I get an error:

> Referential mapping on the column idDetailsUtilisateur.

I don't understand because the table `detailsUtilisateur` had a column `idDetailsUtilisateur` which is a primary key and a foreign key, why did I get this error? Thank you

Comment: Please always show the exact original error message

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing the identity(1,1) on detailsUtilisateur table, but I don't understand why I needed to remove this ? Can someone explain me this?

Comment: I have a doubt why you set the same field as primary key as well as foreign key in user details table, as foreign key always allow duplicates and primary refers to uniqueness...

Comment: First, this is not truly a 1 to 1 relationship.  It's a 1 to 0..1 relationship, because you can create a Utilisateur row without a corresponding detailsUtilisateur row.  However, you cannot create a detailsUtilisateur row without previously having a matching Utilisateur row.  Second, if the rows are out of sequence then the identities generated will be different and one will not exist.

Comment: I think the following links will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680680/can-foreign-key-refer-to-primary-key-in-same-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680680/can-foreign-key-refer-to-primary-key-in-same-table) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982992/is-it-fine-to-have-foreign-key-as-primary-key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982992/is-it-fine-to-have-foreign-key-as-primary-key)