# Database - Employee & manager relationship - constraints

Tags: sql, database-design, rdbms

In an employee table which has structure like below -

```
EMP_NO | EMP_NAME | MANAGER_NO
```

How we make sure manager is someone whose record is already there in emp table and also make sure emp is not manager of himself?

Comment: Yes. Create a Foreign Key. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680680/can-foreign-key-refer-to-primary-key-in-same-table

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, I thought we can not create foreign key referencing primary key in same table

Comment: The link says it's possible, though I haven't tried it. The question you ask is database specific - please indicate which database you are using (SQL Server, Oracle MySQL etc.). To make sure emp is not his own manager you use a check constraint ensuring that the two field values are always different

Comment: I checked it in Oracle and it works fine. Thank you @Nick.McDermaid