# pymysql - FOREIGN KEY CREATE TABLE

Tags: python, pymysql

Hi I'm trying to insert a foreign key when I create a table in **pymysql** but get an error. This is my code:

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artist(id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, full_name varchar,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES song(artist_id))''')

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song(id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar,
artist_id int, entry_date timestamp, entry_position int)''')
```

Comment: execute CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Song query first

Comment: it's better to mentioned error that you got,and it easy to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the name and full name column you should add size as `varchar(10)` or some thing.
and other error is you are tried to use id as primary and foreign key in artist table
for that refer this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680680/can-a-foreign-key-refer-to-a-primary-key-in-the-same-table)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one artist can be the author of many songs, then this should be the other way around: the foreign key must be defined on the Song table and reference the Artist table.