# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'projects_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'employees'

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, error-code

```
CREATE DATABASE employeeDB;
USE employeeDB;

CREATE TABLE employees(
    employeeid NUMERIC(9),
    firstname VARCHAR(10),
    lastname VARCHAR(20),
    deptCode CHAR(5),
    salary NUMERIC(9, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (employeeid)
);

CREATE TABLE projects(
    projectid CHAR(8),
    deptcode CHAR(5),
    description VARCHAR(200),
    startdate DATE,
    stopdate DATE,
    revenue NUMERIC(12, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (projectid),
    FOREIGN KEY (deptcode) REFERENCES employees(deptCode)
);

CREATE TABLE departments(
    code CHAR(5),
    name VARCHAR(5),
    managerid NUMERIC(9),
    subdeptof CHAR(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (code),
    FOREIGN KEY (managerid) REFERENCES employees(employeeid),
    FOREIGN KEY (subdeptof) REFERENCES projects(deptcode)
);

ALTER TABLE employees ADD FOREIGN KEY (deptCode) REFERENCES projects(deptcode);
```

Something wrong at the line CREATE TABLE projects(...). When I run the code in MySQL it give the Error Code 1822. What is the problem ? Any expert can help ?

Comment: in `employees` table you have defined an primary key column `employeeid`.
There is no primary key with `deptCode` column.
And you are creating FK in `projects` table, that is connected with employees by `deptcode` column, instead table `projects` should be connected with `employees` by primary key column, which is: `employeeid`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a foreign key refer to a primary key in the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680680/can-a-foreign-key-refer-to-a-primary-key-in-the-same-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create a foreign key with a non-primary key, and if you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key (column), the column must be indexed with a unique constraint on it.
So either create a unique constraint on `deptCode` column, reference by already existing primary key, or change the primary key.

Comment: How to indexed the column with a unique constraint on it ?

Comment: @emperor_c: In your example it can be achieved by running : `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX employees_deptcode_uniq
ON employees(deptCode)`